# My radon manometer has a red reading, what should I do?

Tags: radon

We purchased a home a few years ago and it has a radon mitigation system. I just happened to go downstairs and look at it and noticed this reading. What should I check? Should I be alarmed?

[image: meter photo]

**EDIT**

Thank you for the link to the manual. The fan is on a pipe coming out of the house and is plugged in to the outlet on the side of the house. I can't tell (tried both listening and feeling for vibration) if it's running and I checked to ensure that the breaker hadn't been flipped.

As for checking the oil - I haven't quite been able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: I'm guessing this system has a fan. Is it still running?

Comment: The fan would have to run backwards to get that reading. Disconnect the supply tube and try to adjust to zero. If you can't, try the fill button. If that doesn't work, you probably need more gauge oil.

Comment: Here is a link to the manual; http://www.dwyer-inst.com/PDF_files/mark2_iom.pdf

Comment: To check if the fan is working, you can put a plastic bag over the end of the exhaust pipe and see if it inflates.

Gauge oil is just the orange fluid that goes in the manometer (pressure meter) tube that indicates the pressure difference being driven by the fan. If it is missing or low, then it could give the negative reading. It should go to zero when the fan if off (as long as the wind isn't blowing too hard).

Comment: Not the sort of thing to be experimenting with: get a manufacturer's rep or someone who really knows about this sort of thing. At best, they will show you how to check (with confidence)

Comment: A radon system is pretty simple technology: pipe with a fan.

Comment: Not sure how DIY advice is to call the manufacturer or someone...

Comment: @BMitch ultimately what happened was that the fan had stopped running. I don't know why/how it stopped working, but we had someone come out and check it and they unplugged it and plugged it back in and it started working.

Comment: @littleturtle thank you for your comment. it was very helpful and i would accept an answer along the lines of your comment.

Comment: @swasheck thanks for following up. If littleturtle doesn't respond, we welcome self-answers here.

Comment: Maybe this is not the place to do it oneself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if the fan is working, you can put a plastic bag over the end of the exhaust pipe and see if it inflates.

Gauge oil is just the orange fluid that goes in the manometer (pressure meter) tube that indicates the pressure difference being driven by the fan. If it is missing or low, then it could give the negative reading. It should go to zero when the fan if off (as long as the wind isn't blowing too hard).

Even if the bag inflates, it may not be creating a strong enough pressure difference, so you should make sure there is the proper amount of gauge oil in the manometer.